# CSS Grid - auto column height

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

The `cart form` is stretching vertically and the `thumbs` are positioning in the bottom left corner, when I'd like them to sit directly under the cart form like so:

[image]

```css
.product-page--main-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.product-page--main-content>* {
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.product-page--cart-form-block {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.product-page--thumbs {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.product-page--images {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 3;
  height: 400px;
}

.product-page--description {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-page--main-content">
  <div class="product-page--title-n-vendor">Title</div>
  <div class="product-page--cart-form-block">Cart form</div>
  <div class="product-page--thumbs">Thumbs</div>
  <div class="product-page--images">Images</div>
  <div class="product-page--description">Description</div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/paulmason/pen/rYXyYW

Comment: The images and question are confusing. The image has four rows. but your work has 3 rows. You could also change the code for that to `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);` or `grid-template-rows:3;` since they are evenly spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is working perfectly, as written.

Your image grid item is set to `height: 400px`.

```
.product-page--images {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 3;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Then you have 50px in top and bottom padding.

```
.product-page--main-content > * {
    padding: 50px 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

So the image grid item is 500px tall, in a row set to `1fr`, in a grid with three rows. It all works perfectly, as specified.

Maybe what you want is **four** rows:

```css
.product-page--main-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto; */ /* now defaults to grid-auto-rows: auto */
}
.product-page--main-content > * {
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.product-page--cart-form-block {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.product-page--thumbs {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.product-page--images {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 4;            /* changed from 3 */
  height: 400px;
}

.product-page--description {
  grid-row: span 4;            /* changed from 3 */
}
```

```html
<div class="product-page--main-content">
  <div class="product-page--title-n-vendor">Title</div>
  <div class="product-page--cart-form-block">Cart form</div>
  <div class="product-page--thumbs">Thumbs</div>
  <div class="product-page--images">Images</div>
  <div class="product-page--description">Description</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking but this seems to fit: change

```
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
```

to

```
grid-template-rows: 3;
```